# Uniform shuffle in python

Tags: python, shuffle, uniform

I have a dataset with N records, some features and two targets (0 and 1). The ratio of the targets is 4/1. There are 80% of records with target 0 followed by 20% of records with target 1 in an array.

I need to shuffle my array uniform-likely for these targets.

I use `np.shuffle` for now, because I split my data to train and test samples manually (I take first K values of the shuffled array for train and (1 - K) for test). I also was looking at  `model_selection.train_test_split` but didn't find any specifics about way of shuffling.

Comment: What's wrong with np.shuffle?

Comment: @groceryheist I'm just not sure if it shuffles exactly uniformly, according to documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If numpy is acceptable then you want

```
import numpy as np

# x is the array
generator = np.random.default_rnd()
generator.shuffle(x)
```

Comment: I had to add default_rng, then it worked.